# 301 Redirect Direct Traffic only

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I don't know if this is good practice or not but we are looking to have traffic redirected to our new site but only from direct traffic or by going to the root (index) of the website from a search engine.

So anyone who types it into the address bar www.test.com is then redirected to www.test2.com for example and also anyone who does a Google search and clicks a result for the homepage is then redirected from www.test.com to www.test2.com

Then if any does a Google search and arrives on the website apart from the index/homepage (a product for example) they are then redirect after X amount of seconds using Javascript (which I can sort out no problem) not using 301.

Its just the 301 redirect for direct traffic and search traffic hitting the homepage.

Not sure if something can be done using PHP rather than using .htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted an php solution

put this on your index.php before any output

```
// Permanent redirection
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.newWebSite.com/");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

For a PHP solution, Nicolas is correct.

If you wanted to do it with `mod_rewrite` in your `.htaccess` file, you could simply do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://test2.com/ [R=301,L]
```

If you have other references to your home page as well, such as `index.php`, then you can use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(index.php)?$ http://test2.com/ [R=301,L]
```

To be safe, I would make this the very first rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` file